# Gulp SCSS Color Variables to css

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have a scss file with over 20 lines of color variables. I want to create a css file with these variables to have one class for color and class for background-color.

**Example:**

from scss variable

```
$color-red: #FF0000;
```

to css

```
.color-red { color:#FF0000; }
.bg-color-red { background-color:#FF0000; }
```

Is there any  Gulp plugin that allows me to do it?
any recomendation accepted but i need to do it with gulp if it is possible.

Comment: This is a common thing Sass users want that I ran into, as well, some time ago: use Sass maps instead of a variable for each colour! You can loop over your map easily that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chriskirknielsen suggested, sass maps and the `@each` rule is a good choice here.  This is the first time I have used these concepts but this works in my testing.

Your `colors.scss` file would look like this:

```
$colors: ("color-red": "#FF0000", "color-green": "#00ff40");  // etc.

@each $color, $value in $colors {
  .#{$color} {
    color: #{$value};
  }
  .bg-#{$color} {
    background-color: #{$value};
  }
}
```

The `gulp-sass` output in `colors.css` is:

```
.color-red {
  color: #FF0000; }

.bg-color-red {
  background-color: #FF0000; }

.color-green {
  color: #00ff40; }

.bg-color-green {
  background-color: #00ff40; }
```

See https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#do-something-for-every-pair